# Return list of all users in BOX Enterprise Account

Tags: box-api

I would like to export a list of all users in our Enterprise account. However, it would seem that my co-admin credentials fail to execute the example request listed in the BOX.com API 2.0 documentation:

curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"

The documentation indicates that this should return the current user's information if executed by a non-admin. However, in my case I am receiving a 403 Forbidden error. Am I missing something or executing this wrong? Does this API command require the main enterprise admin credentials? If I execute with the URL "https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me" it successfully returns my account information.

Comment: Just to confirm: does the info returned by users/me indicate that you are in fact a co-admin?

Comment: Yes, users/me indicates coadmin for my role. I had to add role as included field as it was not included with the default response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this when logged in as an admin or coadmin. This appears to be a bug on our end. We're trying to fix it ASAP–I'll update here when it's been fixed.

Comment: The bug appears to be fixed. Thanks!