# Privileges required to return the list of enterprise users in Box

Tags: get, box-api

This question has been raised before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700014/return-list-of-all-users-in-box-enterprise-account), but I am getting the same issue, despite being added as a co-admin under my account. The previous question does not make it clear as to what the fix was to get it working, hence me asking again.

I am trying to get a list of users using the following GET request:

https://api.box.com/2.0/users

I am setting the Authorization header with a valid access token. However, when I make the request I get back a 403 Forbidden error, with the message "The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token".

Just to prove the tokens are correct, I am able to get my own user information using the https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me API, which return a JSON object with my information.

So my question is, is there anything else I need to do/configure to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to give your access tokens enterprise-level privileges, you must enable the `Manage an Enterprise` scope in your Box application.

[image]