# Access denied error message when trying to create a shared link to a folder in Box

Tags: post, permissions, box-api, directory

So following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098865/privileges-required-to-return-the-list-of-enterprise-users-in-box) around permissions to add collaborators, I am now having further permissions issues when trying to create a shared link to a folder in Box using the API.

So to confirm, I have the "Manage an enterprise" scope now enabled on the API account.

Here is the error message I am getting back:

```
{"type":"error","status":403,"code":"access_denied_insufficient_permissions","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Access denied - insufficient permission","request_id":"2137493926531843e3c61af"}
```

Here is the POST data I am sending:

```
{"shared_link":{"access":"collaborators"}}
```

Here is the URL that I am sending it to:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/1561835651
```

The folder Id is for a folder I have created using the API, and I am also able to add collaborators to that folder OK, so up until this point, I have all the correct permissions to perform these operations.

So my question is, what else should I be doing? I cannot see any more options against the account to suggest I need more permissions, and the documentation is not clear on what else I need to do to be able to perform this operation.

Comment: Are you able to successfully create shared_link with "open" or "company" wide access level?

I understand that you want to to collaborations working properly, but just trying to verify that link sharing works in a first place.

Answer (score 0):

For CreateSharedLink method, the HTTP action is PUT. If use POST method, it will return 403 sharedlink access_denied_insufficient_permissions error.
-Ivy