# Box.com shared link on folder

Tags: php, permissions, box-api, shared-directory

I'm using this php class for box.com 
https://github.com/golchha21/BoxPHPAPI

I have made my own function to share a folder like this

```
public function share_folder($folder_id) {
    $url = $this->build_url("/folders/".$folder_id);
    $params = array('shared_link' => array('access' => 'open', 'permissions' =>
        array('can_download' => 'true', 'can_preview' => 'true')));
    return json_decode($this->post($url, json_encode($params)), true);
}
```

I'm having the same issue as this post.
[Access denied error message when trying to create a shared link to a folder in Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220942/access-denied-error-message-when-trying-to-create-a-shared-link-to-a-folder-in-b/22720852#22720852)

Does anyone have a fix for this or know why it's happening?

**Update**

I figured it out:

```
    public function share_folder($folder_id) {
                $url = $this->build_url("/folders/".$folder_id);
                $params = array('shared_link' => array('access' => 'open', 'permissions' =>
array('can_download' => true, 'can_preview' => true)));
                return json_decode($this->put($url, $params), true);
```

I have to change it to put and take off the json_encode

Hope this help someone else

Answer (score 0):

The API is now updated with the sharing function.

```
<?php
    include('library/BoxAPI.class.php');

    $client_id      = 'CLIENT ID';
    $client_secret  = 'CLIENT SECRET';
    $redirect_uri   = 'REDIRECT URL';

    $box = new Box_API($client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_uri);

    if(!$box->load_token()){
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
            $token = $box->get_token($_GET['code'], true);
            if($box->write_token($token, 'file')){
                $box->load_token();
            }
        } else {
            $box->get_code();
        }
    }

    // Share folder
    $params['shared_link']['access'] = 'ACCESS TYPE'; //open|company|collaborators
    print_r($box->share_folder('FOLDER ID', $params));

    // Share file
    $params['shared_link']['access'] = 'ACCESS TYPE'; //open|company|collaborators
    print_r($box->share_file('File ID', $params);
?>
```

Have a look [here](http://www.ulhas.net/GitHub/BoxPHPAPI/)
Download: [BoxPHPAPI](https://github.com/golchha21/BoxPHPAPI)